# What noun do you use for an occasion of below zero temperatures?

Tags: word-choice

What noun do you use for a period of very cold weather in which temperature drops below zero? Can I use the word *frost* For example:

> There was a strong **frost** last night.

Comment: What do you mean by *occasion*? Do you mean there was snow? Or that it was just very cold? Also, there's a typo with *night* in your phrase.

Comment: The dictionary says that "frost" is the word. But is it really used to mean a temperture below zero?

Comment: @Lambie I don't know where you are, but the question makes perfect sense to me. Here in the UK, the weather forecaster often says "There will be a frost tonight, so protect your tender plants" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary says that "frost" is the word.

> A Frost: The cold weather that causes these ice crystals to form.

It really is used to mean a temperture below zero Celcius.

> You can expect a frost tonight.

In this sense the word is usually countable.

Weather presenters might distiguish between a ground frost and an air frost (in a ground frost, the air at about 1m is still above freezing, and only the ground is lightly frozen.  If the temperature is well below zero you can say "a hard frost"

Comment: A frost is overnight and does not mean: a period of very cold weather. It is a temporary phenomenon, usually lasting overnight and disappearing in the morning.

Comment: I've certaintly heard "The frost will last all day".  It would be strange to have a frost during the day but not at night. However I don't think this is impossible.

Comment: A frost is a frost. Frosts are simply not usually "a period of very cold weather". And his Russian<>English dictionary is what he should have consulted here. Not us, really. He's taking the piss (as the Brits say).

Comment: But the actual example: "There was a strong frost last night" only errs in its use of "strong".  Though I agree you would not likely say "last week was a frost".  However In Orlando Woolf talks about a frost lasting over a month (and the thames freezing over)

Answer (score 1):

The adjective applied to frost isn't **strong**, but more usually **hard**, when the temperature falls below freezing point (although a mild ground frost can occur when the air temperature is above freezing).

> There was a hard frost last night.

Another way to say it would be

> It was freezing last night.

Answer (score 1):

"The question: What noun do you use for a period of very cold weather in which temperature drops below zero? Can I use the word frost For example:

There was a strong frost last night." [strong=heavy frost is better].

Answer: Not really. Please see below.

**Freeze and frost are not the same.** A freeze lasts for a longer period of time.
Frost is formed overnight and usually disappears when the sun comes up and the temperature rises. Frost can be severe but it does not last. A freeze lasts as long as the temperature stays below 32°F (0°C).

Formal definition of frost from a US government website:

> Frost (Abbrev. FRST) - Frost describes the formation of thin ice
>   crystals on the ground or other surfaces in the form of scales,
>   needles, feathers, or fans. Frost develops under conditions similar to
>   dew, except the temperatures of the Earth's surface and earthbound
>   objects falls below 32°F. **As with the term "freeze," this condition
>   is primarily significant during the growing season.** If a frost
>   period is sufficiently severe to end the growing season or delay its
>   beginning, it is commonly referred to as a "killing frost." Because
>   frost is primarily an event that occurs as the result of radiational
>   cooling, it frequently occurs with a thermometer level temperature in
>   the mid-30s.

[official definition from a weather website](https://forecast.weather.gov/glossary.php?word=frost)

However, a freeze is different:

> **Freeze**
>   **A freeze is when the surface air temperature is expected to be 32°F or below over a widespread area for a climatologically significant
>   period of time. Use of the term is usually restricted to advective
>   situations or to occasions when wind or other conditions prevent
>   frost.** "Killing" may be used during the growing season when the
>   temperature is expected to be low enough for a sufficient duration to
>   kill all but the hardiest herbaceous crops.

[note the adjective, advective, for adverse]

So, a period of very cold weather (not an overnight or short period of time) would be a period of freezing temperatures, where freezing means very cold and below the freezing mark.

- "We've had below-freezing temperatures all week." [meaning: very cold]
- "We had a frost last night". [Now, it is day and frost has disappeared]
- "We had a freeze last night. But the crops survived the night. [The temperature goes back up above 32°F (0°C)

**"A long period of cold" in English is not a frost or a freeze.**

Basically, the only term we have in English is "a prolonged period of below-freezing temperatures" **or similar phrasing.** For a frost or freeze to occur, the temperature does need to fall below the freezing mark.

In English, we don't associate the word frost to mean: a **period of very cold weather.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what context you are using this in, but a clear way to say what I think you mean is with the phrase "**below freezing**"  In most of the world "**sub-zero**" might work, but in America sub-zero would be understood as below 0 Fahrenheit.